# Why does Openssl 0.9.8g suddenly changes to 0.9.8b?

Tags: linux, openssl, version

I have a weird problem in which I try to use cryptodev in Openssl version 0.9.8g, but then if an error occurs or the system logs out, the version for Openssl rolls back to 0.9.8b.I have also tried reinstalling, but no dice. The version stays 0.9.8b Anyone know of a fix for this problem?
PS: I am using Intel Tolapai with RedHat 5

Answer (score 1):

The answer is encoded below:

```
sudo find / -name 'libssl*'
```

Chances are there is more than one libssl on your machine. You can find the version number by doing something like `strings - /usr/lib/libssl* | less` and then search for the version number by typing `/0\.9\.8` followed by ENTER.